# How should I write new code when the old codebase and the environment uses lots of globals in PHP

Tags: design, php, refactoring, maintenance

I'm working in the Wordpress environment which itself heavily relies on globals and the codebase I'm maintaining introduces some more. I want this to change and so I'm trying to think how should I handle this.

For the globals our code has introduced I think I will set them as dependencies in the constructor or in getter / setter so that I don't rely on them being globals and then refactor the old codebase little by little so that we have no globals.

With Wordpress globals I was thinking to wrap all WP globals inside a Wrapper class and hide them in there. Like this

```
class WpGlobals {
    public static function getDb() {
        global $wpdb;
        return $wpdb;
    }
}
```

Would this be of any help? The idea is that I centralize all globals in one class and do not scatter them through the code, so that if Wordpress kills one of them I need to modify code only in one place.

What would you do?

Answer (score 1):

I recently started working on a Wordpress project. We wrap all calls to Wordpress functions into a wrapper class. This makes it easy to unit test our code.

I have a function that returns the db connection like you do. This way I can mock it.